# randomSplit returns dataframe with all zero values in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to split my data into training and testing sets but its not working properly because it is returning datasets with all zero values. How do I fix this?

Note* My data has a lot more samples but I have included only the first four for clarity.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
data = pd.read_csv('path')
header=data.columns.tolist()
fn=header[:data.shape[1]-1]
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=fn,outputCol="features")
spDF = sql.createDataFrame(data)
spDF.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+----+---+---+------+----+---+---+----+
|  a|  b|  c|   d|  e|  f|     g|   h|  i|  j|Type|
+---+---+---+----+---+---+------+----+---+---+----+
|  7|  0|  2| 700|  9| 10|  1153| 832|  9|  2|   1|
| 17|  7|  4|1230| 17| 19|  1265|1230| 17|  0|   0|
|  0|  0|  0|   0|  0|  0|     0|   0|  0|  0|   0|
| 31| 22|  3|3812| 39| 37| 18784|4380| 39|  8|   0|
+---+---+---+----+---+---+------+----+---+---+----+

spDF = assembler.transform(spDF)
spDF.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+----+---+---+------+----+---+---+----+--------------------+
|  a|  b|  c|   d|  e|  f|     g|   h|  i|  j|Type|            features|
+---+---+---+----+---+---+------+----+---+---+----+--------------------+
|  7|  0|  2| 700|  9| 10|  1153| 832|  9|  2|   1|[7.0,0.0,2.0,700....|
| 17|  7|  4|1230| 17| 19|  1265|1230| 17|  0|   0|[17.0,7.0,4.0,123...|
|  0|  0|  0|   0|  0|  0|     0|   0|  0|  0|   0|          (10,[],[])|
| 31| 22|  3|3812| 39| 37| 18784|4380| 39|  8|   0|[31.0,22.0,3.0,38...|
+---+---+---+----+---+---+------+----+---+---+----+--------------------+
(train_data, test_data) = spDF.randomSplit([0.8,0.2])
train_data.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----------+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|  f|  g|  h|  i|  j|Type|  features|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----------+
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|   0|(10,[],[])|
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|   0|(10,[],[])|
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|   0|(10,[],[])|
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|   0|(10,[],[])|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----------+
```

I want to pass this training data to fit a machine learning model.

Comment: try adding `seed` value to it and see if you get non-zero values in the set. Follow the link for reference -> https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.3/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.randomSplit

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machne-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `apache-spark-sql`).

Comment: it's very likely that the internal library rounds up the number of samples, why don't you try with more samples?

Comment: Please include explicitly your *imports*

Comment: @kaysush I have already tried that but I get the same result.

Comment: @Alberto Bonsanto My data has a lot more samples but I have included only the first four for clarity.

Comment: @desertnaut I have edited the post. Kindly see to it.

Comment: Are you sure it is not due to the original dataframe containing a lot of all zero rows? Did you look through all rows in both obtained dataframes (or use e.g. `describe`)?